# Install svn on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, svn

Hi I'm trying to install svn on my Ubuntu 12.04 server. I've installed Subversion and Apache. Is there something else i need to install to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After that you have to configure your server for SVN.

**Server Configuration**

This step assumes you have installed above mentioned packages on your system. This section explains how to create SVN repository and access the project.

**Create SVN Repository**

There are several typical places to put a Subversion repository; most common places are: `/srv/svn`, `/usr/local/svn` and `/home/svn`. For clarity's sake, we'll assume we are putting the Subversion repository in `/home/svn`, and your project's name is simply 'myproject'

There are also several common ways to set permissions on your repository. However, this area is the most common source of errors in installation, so we will cover it thoroughly. Typically, you should choose to create a new group called 'subversion' that will own the repository directory. To do this

- Choose System > Administration > Users and Groups from your Ubuntu menu.
- Click the 'Manage Groups' button.
- Click the 'Add' button.
- Name the group 'subversion'
- Add yourself and www-data (the Apache user) as users to this group

  (Note: in order to see www-data you may need to see FixShowAllUsers) 
  Click 'OK', then click 'Close' twice to commit your changes and exit the app.

You have to logout and login again before you are a member of the subversion group, and can do check ins.

Now issue the following commands:

```
   $ sudo mkdir /home/svn
   $ cd /home/svn
   $ sudo mkdir myproject
```

The SVN repository can be created using the following command:

```
   $ sudo svnadmin create /home/svn/myproject
```

And use the following commands to correct file permissions:

```
   $ cd /home/svn
   $ sudo chown -R www-data:subversion myproject
   $ sudo chmod -R g+rws myproject
```

The last command sets gid for proper permissions on all new files added to your Subversion repository.

If you want to use WebDAV as an access method described below, repeat the chmod -R g+rws myproject command again. This is because svnadmin will create directories and files without group write access. This is no problem for read only access or using the custom svn protocol but when Apache tries to commit changes to the repository linux will deny it access. Also the owner and group are set as root. This can be changed by repeating the chown and chgrp commands listed above.

Credit goes to [Ubuntu-Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Subversion)

for more information : [subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)

information about adding users/groups : [Ubuntu -Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto)

Comment: how can i create groups with command?

Comment: I can give you command , more than that this document can help you . https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AddUsersHowto

Answer (score 1):

To install Subversion, run the following command from a terminal prompt:

`sudo apt-get install subversion libapache2-svn`

I have searched and came to know that Ubuntu have a good Documentation for Subversion that can help you to get more information on usage of it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/subversion.html